# Ambiguous Evaluation of Lambda Expression on Array

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

I would like to use a `lambda` that adds one to x if x is equal to zero. I have tried the following expressions:

```
t = map(lambda x: x+1 if x==0 else x, numpy.array())
t = map(lambda x: x==0 and x+1 or x, numpy.array())
t = numpy.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x+1 if x==0 else x, 0, numpy.array())
```

Each of these expressions returns the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

My understanding of `map()` and `numpy.apply_along_axis()` was that it would take some function and apply it to each value of an array. From the error it seems that the the lambda is being evaluated as `x=array`, not some value in array. What am I doing wrong?

I know that I could write a function to accomplish this but I want to become more familiar with the functional programming aspects of python.

Comment: What is `numpy.array`?  I assume it's not the numpy function of that name?  What is the data you're trying to apply this to?

Comment: It works for me; for example, `map(lambda x: x+1 if x==0 else x, np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]))` evaluates to `[1, 1, 2, 3]`, as expected. Please provide a minimal working example that exhibits the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Is your array multidimensional?

Comment: On a side note, `x+1 if x==0` can be written as `1 if x==0` or `1 if not x`. `x==0 and x+1 or x` I find not very clear. Perhaps the shortest form for it all is `x if x else 1`.

Comment: BrenBarn, I was just trying to make it clear that I was using an array generated by numpy.array(). I was not passing it the function numpy.array.

Comment: @Joe: Can you show an actual example with an actual array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using numpy, you should be writing vectorised code:

```
arr + (arr == 0)
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @Joe looping over every element of a large array in Python is slow.  Arithmetic, logical and comparison operators on a numpy array are treated elementwise, so this will give you the result in a far more efficient form.

Comment: I get the goal of vectorization, I just don't exactly understand how the expression you posted works.

Comment: @Joe `(arr == 0)` gives a boolean array that is `True` where `arr` is equal to `0`.  In arithmetic, `True` is converted to `1` and `False` to `0`, so this adds `1` where `arr` is equal to `0`.